# Float interference with lettrine.sty

Tags: lettrine

When using the package lettrine.sty, I have noticed an annoying interference between drop caps and floats.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\title{My title}
\maketitle
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \vspace{-20pt}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image.jpg}
        \end{center}
        \vspace{-20pt}
        \caption{\textit{My caption}
        \vspace{-10pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
\section{My text}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
%\lettrine[lines=3,slope=0pt,nindent=1pt]{L}{orem} ipsum dolor sit...
\end{document}
```

This LaTex seems to compile fine, however as soon as I add a drop cap to the first word, the LaTex starts behaving weirdly and I get the body overlapping with the image. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Please for future questions always make sure your example code is a complete document that demonstrates the problem. The example here is not complete, has mis-matched `{}` and does not use lettrine or drop caps at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry about that, code is now fixed. Regarding the actual problem, do you know of a simpler solution to the one that you linked, consisting of changing the figure type of the image?

Comment: People still can't use your example to see a problem, you should use the `[demo]` option so it uses a black rectangle not your image (which we don't have) and you should use lettrine with settings that show the problem. But if I knew of a simpler answer I would have answered the other question more simply. Both are complicated packages "cutting holes" in the paragraph shape for the image or the drop cap, merging the two to cut two holes in the same paragraph isn't simple at all.

Comment: (Actually the code is still not working.)